# Index error: String out of range, but it shouldn't be going out of range?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption

Alright so I am making an encoder/decoder and currently I'm testing to see if my idea will work, but I keep getting the error telling me my string index is out of range when it shouldn't be going out of range in the first place.

```
message = "abc"
#Should come out as 212223
translated = ' '


n = 1
while n >= 0:
    t = message[n]
    if t == 'a':
        translated = translated + '21'
    elif t == 'b':
        translated = translated + '22'
    elif t == 'c':
        translated = translated + '23'
    while n <= len(message):
        n = n + 1
print(translated)
```

It makes perfect sense to me so I had a hard time searching for appropriate help that solves for what I am doing, so can I have some help? A link, a solution, what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
n = 0
while n >= 0:
```

You have an infinite loop as you keep on incrementing `n`. 
At some point `message[n]` will get out of range.

You should move the `while n <= len(message):` to be your main loop instead of your current one.

A better way will be to iterate directly over `message` with a `for` loop:

```
for t in message:
    if t == 'a':
        translated = translated + '21'
    elif t == 'b':
        translated = translated + '22'
    elif t == 'c':
        translated = translated + '23'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
while n <= len(message):
    n = n + 1
```

Should need changing to:

```
while n < len(message):
    n = n + 1
```

The last index of a string will be `len(message) - 1`, as indexing starts at 0.
I would just set n to len(message) - 1 instantly instead however.

Answer (score 0):

Because at last loop you are using t = message[3]..It is the cause of your error. If you  message variable contain  "abc" then you can access only t = message[0], t = message[1], t = message[2]. So try this

```
message = "abc"
#Should come out as 212223
translated = ' '


n = 1
while n >= 0:
    t = message[n-1]
    if t == 'a':
        translated = translated + '21'
    elif t == 'b':
        translated = translated + '22'
    elif t == 'c':
        translated = translated + '23'
    while n <= len(message):
        n = n + 1
print(translated)
```